# How to get the socket-id in Angular using Socket-io.client

Tags: socket.io, angular6, client-side

In my angular app I am using `socket.io-client` npm package to make a socket-io communication to another node-server.

I have the following code forthe same.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

 constructor() { }
 private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
 private socket;


 getLiveData1() {
   let observable = new Observable(observer => {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
    console.log("THIS SOCKET IS:getLiveData1");
    this.socket.on('connect', function() {
     console.log("on connect:THIS SOCKET IS id is");

     console.log(this.socket.id);

     console.log(this.socket.socket.id);
    });
    this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
    observer.next(data);
  });
  return () => {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
})
return observable;
}
```

I am trying to access the client id only on the `connect` event. 
 this.socket.on('connect', function() {
     console.log("on connect:THIS SOCKET IS id is");

```
 console.log(this.socket.id);

 console.log(this.socket.socket.id);
});
```

however both the log-statements where i am trying to log the socket-id using : `this.socket.id or this.socket.socket.id` errors out saying that `this.socket` is `undefined`
**How can i get the client-side socket-id in this case?**

Answer (score 0):

From docs 
https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-id

socket.id
(String)
An unique identifier for the socket session. Set after the connect event is triggered, and updated after the reconnect event.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost');

console.log(socket.id); // undefined

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // 'G5p5...'
});
```

You doing it right, your problem that you are using es5 function, that doesn't keep `this` context. Replace it with arrow functions. Or bind context.

```
this.socket.on('connect', /* arrow function */() => {
     console.log("on connect:THIS SOCKET IS id is");

     console.log(this.socket.id);
});
```

Comment: `const socket = io('http://localhost');

console.log(socket.id); // undefined

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.id);  //   this gives a typescript compile tie error saying 'socket' is undefined. if i try to use "this.socket.id" it again gives as undefined.
});`

Comment: Could you add full code snippet. It cannot say 'socket' is 'undefined', because it worked fine with 'socket.on(' - if socket would be undefined it wouldn't manage to call socket.on.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (Angular 6)

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
this.socket.on('connect', this.socketOnConnect)}
```

above is the initialization code for socket and binding an angular method to "ON CONNECT" method

```
  socketOnConnect() {
console.log('connected');
var socket = this;
console.log(socket['id']);  } // prints socket id
```

the socket_on_connect method has a scope of Socket itself, so if we use `this` inside the method, it displays socket object. hence the above method works

npms used

```
"@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32"
 "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
```